# Resetting automatic slideshows

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm adding a feature where the user can add their own pictures to an automatic slideshow and manage them; it works fine but I noticed a weird behaviour with the slideshow. The images aren't synchronized and they just keep appearing or disappearing out of nowhere, without even transitions sometimes. I don't know what exactly causes it but so far, I know the issue is coming from the opacity values. My guess is that the slideshow gets confused with all those `setTimeout();` functions and the past ones simply keep running. Even if that's the case, I'm not sure how it can be fixed.

Note: There can be multiple slideshows on the same page, so it runs the code for each one of them.

Every time the page is loaded or an image is added, this code is run:

```
function showSlides(slides, slideIndex, cycle) {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = "0";
    };
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    };
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(function() {
        showSlides(slides, slideIndex, cycle)
    }, cycle);
};
                                                        
var slideshow = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
    for (let s = 0; s < slideshow.length; s++) {
    var cycle = slideshow[s].dataset.cycle;
    var slides = slideshow[s].querySelectorAll('.image');
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides(slides, slideIndex, cycle);
};
```

**HTML (before a new picture is added to the DOM)**

```
<div class="slideshow" data-cycle="5000">
    <img alt="An image" class="image" src="image1.jpg"/>
    <img alt="An image" class="image" src="image2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you add the new images to the DOM?

For example, you append node. You need obviously to parse your DOM every time the new image is added. I don't see that in your code. Your function showSlides() is always invoked with the same parameters (the initial ones). You should call your settimeout outside your main function (not in a recursion way as in your example). And then you pass some parameters that will be changed each time the new image is added.

I would concider to use some object for storing the parameters of slider.

```
const sliders = {
    slideshow: document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow"),

    function showSlides(slides, slideIndex, cycle) {
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.opacity = "0";
        };
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        };
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.opacity = '1';
    },
    // You put everything you need for your sliders here, even you can create an array with all your sliders objects
}

var cycle, slides, slideIndex=0;

setInterval(function() {
    for (let s = 0; s < sliders.slideshow.length; s++) {
        cycle = sliders.slideshow[s].dataset.cycle;
        slides = sliders.slideshow[s].querySelectorAll('.image');
        sliders.showSlides(slides, slideIndex, cycle);
    }
}, cycle);
```

It's not the best or the most effective way, there is a lot of refactoring to do. But it's just an idea - you need to renew your parameters and to call function in with new parameters. The better option would be to create you custom Event and dispatch it every time you add a picture, and only then to change the values of variables.